# Changing alpha of single pixel value?

Tags: unity, textures, color

I'm trying to change the alpha values of a grayscale texture based on some conditions. Essentially if the color value is within some min and max threshold, set the alpha to 0.8, and if it is not within the thresholds, set it to 0 (unable to see) alpha.

Here's my code so far:

```
    Texture2D UpdateThresholdTexture(Texture2D tex)
    {
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(tex.width, tex.height);

        for (int y = 0; y < texture.height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < texture.width; x++)
            {
                Color color = tex.GetPixel(x, y);

                bool min = color.grayscale >= minThresh;
                bool max = color.grayscale <= maxThresh;

                if (min && max)
                {
                    color.a = 0.8f;
                    texture.SetPixel(x, y, color);
                }
                else
                {
                    color.a = 0f;
                    texture.SetPixel(x, y, color);
                }
            }
        }
        texture.Apply();
        return texture;
    }
```

At the moment it's just returning the original texture. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your code does not return the original texture. What symptom leads you to believe that's what it's doing? Are you drawing this texture with a material that uses alpha blending or otherwise makes the alpha change visible?

Comment: I'm displaying the texture onto a cube. I'm not sure if that negates the opacity or not?

Comment: As I said above, it's the *material* that governs whether alpha is used as opacity, or as some other effect, or ignored entirely. Not the mesh. Show us how you've configured the material that you're using in your cube.

Comment: I managed to solve it, ty for the replies though.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post your solution as an Answer below.